# Fluent Hibernate Insert Fail, Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id',

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am getting an exception on INSERT statement to table using NHibernate

This is how it is called in the Repository (custom) layer

```
private void AddOrUpdateObject(object objectToUpdate)
{
    UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(objectToUpdate);
}
```

This is the SQL Statement generated, i found them in the log

**2013-07-08 15:28:43,919 [36] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - INSERT INTO [Season] (Name, StartDate, EndDate, ModifiedDate) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p0 = 'season 4' [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 6/13/2014 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], @p2 = 12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], @p3 = 7/8/2013 3:28:43 PM [Type: DateTime (0)]**

This is the exception I am getting

**2013-07-08 15:28:43,929 [36] WARN  NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'ticketing.social.dbo.Season'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.**

Why can't it insert a new row to the table "Season", even if it is using  select SCOPE_IDENTITY();

Instead of CurrentSession.SaveorUpdate(), is there another method I could use from ISession?

Please advise, many thanks

Comment: Please, add your mapping class to the question. I bet you're missing the `Id` definition part

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a SQL exception, and your query appears ok, it appears that your ORM is set up correctly, but your database is not. I'd bet your column is not actually an `IDENTITY` column in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not setting the ID in your insert list.  See:

```
INSERT INTO [Season] (Name, StartDate, EndDate, ModifiedDate)
```

No ID there.  So the DB tries to insert NULL for ID which is not allowed.

Comment: the problem is because I just did a data export, no index or primary key were copied over

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Fluent NHibernate, I'll assume that you're mapping your classes with Fluent mapping, and not auto mapping.

In your mapping class, you must define how the ID will be generated. I'm assuming that you're using an `IDENTITY` column because of that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()``call.

In that case, you must map it as:

```
this.Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

Comment: this is my model class
public class SeasonMap : ClassMap<Season>
    {
        public SeasonMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native().UnsavedValue("0");

Comment: so you are saying, instead of GeneratedBy.Native, i should be using GeneratedBy.Identity(). I think i should give it a go, and see if that solves the problem

Comment: @doglin Why are you using that mapping? Is it an `identity` on the database?

Comment: It is not my code. I inherited from someone who left the company. In the mapping, the mapped it as an identity in the code, but in DB, it is a primary key.

Comment: @doglin But isn't it an identity on the database as well?